# Testing for the presence of jQuery UI modal dialog or alternative on page

Tags: jquery-ui, selenium, modal-dialog

I was wondering how you can test for the presence of a jQuery UI modal dialog with Selenium.

I have done some Google searching but nothing is abundantly clear.  although this page suggested isVisible():

http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-test-tool/browse_thread/thread/6affc0ef45a1d4a6?pli=1

I would also require to test elements on the dialog and navigate back to the page that the dialog was initiated from.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works with the demo JQuery UI modal dialog at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

```
open | http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
click | css=#demo-config-menu a:contains(Modal dialog)
waitForVisible | dialog-modal
assertText | ui-dialog-title-dialog-modal | Basic modal dialog
assertText | dialog-modal | Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.
click | css=.ui-dialog-titlebar-close
waitForNotVisible | dialog-modal
```

Comment: Does this work if your page contains multiple dialogs ? How would you know which one selenium is handling ?

Answer (score 4):

I've worked on something similar in the past.

Assuming the modal is contained in a div, I'd start with a *'WaitForVisible'* on that to wait until the modal is acutally showing.
Then you can interact with the elements in the normal way, and then have a '*WaitForNotVisible*' once you've finished with it.

If there isn't a convenient containing div, just pick some other element on the modal to wait for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
<td>waitForTextPresent</td>  
<td>Selecione os produtos para impressão</td>
<td></td>
```

You can use this to check dialog by the title